# How to Get only the number from string "Step-1" using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have "Step-1", "Step-2"... etc string.
I  want to get only the number. how can i get it ?

My solution:

```
var stepName = "Step-1";
var stepNumber = Integer.Parse(stepName[5]);

console.log(stepNumber);
```

but It is not good solution because stepName can be "Step-500".
please suggest me a way to get number after "-"

Comment: Split by `'-'` and take the second element (`stepName.split('-')[1]`) or make a slice (`stepName.slice(5)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and then use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get number

```js
var stepName = "Step-1";
const match = stepName.match(/\d+$/);
if(match && match.length) {
    const stepNumber = parseInt(match[0], 10)
    console.log(stepNumber);
}
```

You can also use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) here as:

```js
var stepName = "Step-1";
const splitArr = stepName.split("-")
const stepNumber = parseInt(splitArr[splitArr.length - 1], 10)
console.log(stepNumber);
```

or

```js
var stepName = "Step-1";
const splitArr = stepName.split("-")
const stepNumber = parseInt(splitArr.at(-1), 10)
console.log(stepNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```js
var stepName = "Step-1";
var stepNumber = stepName.split("-")[1];

console.log(Number(stepNumber));

//another example
var stepName = "Step-500";
var stepNumber = stepName.split("-")[1];

console.log(Number(stepNumber));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is not by regex. If your text format would be a constant as `"Step-1"` and your just replacing the number from `1 - 1********` . You can just split them in an array and get the second array.

```js
let step = "Step-500";
const stepArray = step.split("-");

document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = stepArray[1];
```

```html
<p id="step">

</p>
```

So what the code does is it split your string into two and assign it an array

```
stepArray[0] = "step"
stepArray[1] = "500"
```

PS. But again this will only work if you have a constant format of that variable. e.g  "$var1-$var2"

Answer (score 0):

You can do with replace function too, try below code

```
var stepName = "Step-1";
var stepNumber = parseInt(stepName.replace("Step-", ""));
console.log(stepNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var stepName = "Step-1";
var stepNumber = stepName.split("-");

console.log(stepNumber.length - 1);
```